# Checkbox accessibility using tab

Tags: accessibility

I have a table with header and some data. The checkbox used for "SelectAll" purpose is inside  which is not focused while using tab though whole th cell is focused. User is not able to select that checkbox using spacebar key due to this focus issue. While the check boxes for individual rows are working fine. Please suggest.

Comment: `iOS`, `Web`, `macOS`, `Android`, `Windows`?

Comment: Windows. For all browsers.

Comment: Could you post some code or an example page please ?